# In the postman I am getting proper json response but when I hit the service through restTemplate I am getting chinese characters

Tags: java, resttemplate

Code:

```
RestTemplate template=new RestTemplate();  
HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();                                                                             
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);                               
HttpEntity<?> httpEntity=new HttpEntity<>(body,headers);     
ResponseEntity<String> postForEntity = template.postForEntity("url", httpEntity, String.class);
```

Json Response:

> 笀∀琀爀愀渀猀愀挀琀椀漀渀䤀䐀∀㨀∀㄀娀㜀㌀㐀䔀㤀㈀㈀㘀㜀㈀㌀㔀㠀㘀㤀㔀∀Ⰰ∀猀琀愀琀甀猀∀㨀　Ⰰ∀爀攀焀吀猀∀㨀∀㈀　㈀　ⴀ　㐀ⴀ㈀　∀Ⰰ∀愀搀搀爀倀漀椀渀琀䰀椀猀琀∀㨀嬀笀∀爀攀焀䤀搀∀㨀∀㄀娀㜀㌀㐀䔀㤀㈀㈀㘀㜀㈀㌀㔀㠀㘀㤀㔀∀Ⰰ∀爀攀猀椀䌀漀洀∀㨀∀唀∀Ⰰ∀愀搀搀爀倀渀琀吀欀渀∀㨀∀∀紀崀紀

by using this for loop I am able to get the correct json response:

```
for(int i=0; i< response.length(); i++) {
     encoded += ((char) ((int)response.charAt(i) / 256 ));    
}
```

Postman headers:

```
Request Headers: 
Accept:Application/Json
Content-type:Application/Json

Response Headers:
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 04 Jun 2020 15:41:49 GMT
Server →Server Name
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

**But I want to get the response without using this for loop.**

Comment: Its in the code

Comment: And I tried it still not working

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to receive the response in String format and here is the issue. First receive the response as Object, Once you receive the response as Object then try to convert it in String.

```
RestTemplate template=new RestTemplate();  
HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();                                                                             
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);                               
HttpEntity<?> httpEntity=new HttpEntity<>(body,headers);     
ResponseEntity<Object> postForEntity = template.postForEntity("url", httpEntity, Object.class);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to pass "Accept-Language" header. 
It could be possible that postman sends default header value as "en-US"

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the encoding. when sending your request make sure that you add the header

```
Content-type:Application/Json; charset=utf-8
```

And not just

```
Content-type:Application/Json
```

Comment: The problem is in the encoding of the _request body_?

Comment: The problem is how the client interprets the response. It comes in one encoding but is interpreted as another one. So if you as a client send request specifying in your header what is the charset you send your info and expect your answer than the server will send the response in expected encoding and client will interpret it correctly

Comment: Are you saying a server _should_/_must_ decide how to encode its **response body** based on the `Content-Type` header of the **request**? It's unclear to me if that's what you're suggesting. Please edit your answer to clarify.

Comment: Correct. If you tell the server the encoding on your client request the server will encode the response with that encoding

Comment: That's not correct at all. You could write a pathological server that does that, but that's not in any way normal behaviour.

Comment: So a request sending JSON must always get back JSON? A request sending a multipart form must always get a multipart form as a response?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Accept`, `Accept-Charset`, `Accept-Encoding` headers?

Comment: No, if you send request as JSON the response does not have to be JSON. But the charset part may be true

Comment: Guys quick question....For me this problem is happening in my project.

Comment: Just now I created simple class and I tried to hit the same service with restTemplate I am getting proper json response

Comment: So my question is.....This problem is happening bcoz of any one of the dependencies in my project?

Comment: May me the problem is that your original java code runs with default OS encoding (which may be different from UTF-8), and thus your code tries to interpret any string in that encoding. So see how to run your java with UTF-8 encoding. One way to do so is to pass command line parameter is -D i.e. -Dencoding=utf-8.

Comment: @MichaelGantman I tried this System.getProperty("file.encoding") and my system is showing UTF-8 only